# Applicationhost.config is missing

Tags: azure

I've been encountering this problem whenever I try adding a role to my Azure Cloud Project.

[image]

The thing is that whenever I update to an older revision of my code, it works fine. It isnt until I try adding a new role or even removing a role and readding it is when I get an error. Even on new projects I cannot get a role added.

Comment: do you receive this error on the published app on the azure portal or on your debug client on your development machine?

Comment: @AndrewCounts On debug

Comment: Have you performed an update to your solution recently to a newer version of .Net?  Have you updated your development environment to run on a newer version of IIS and it has changed the pipeline mode (classic / integrated)?  Need a bit more context around your app and the environment you're trying to run it in.

Comment: @SimonW The .NET framework version has not changed at all and the IIS is the same. This happens when I debug my application through visual studio. I tried looked at every file in the Cloud project and comparing it to the working one and it seems like everything looked the same.

Answer (score 1):

Number of things to check/try:

1. Set the application pool to ASP.NET 4.0. Make sure the application is set to v4.0 as well. Then restart IIS.
2. Add  the following key to `<system.webServer>` section of Web.Config:

   `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"   />`
3. Check that the file `%userprofile%\documents\IISexpress\config\applicationHost.config` exists and the application has the necessary permissions to access it. (IIS Express)
4. Check the app pool "run as user" and ensure it has rights to the web site directory.
5. Try running VS in administrator mode and see if debug works. (right click the shortcut and select "run as administrator".

Failing the above post the contents of the file from step 3.