# Visual Studio 2013 Debug with Azure Cloud Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure

all.

I'm having some trouble debugging a local MVC Web Project in VS 2013.  I created an empty solution, then clicked "New Project" and added an "Azure Cloud Service" project, at which point I selected an MVC WebRole / MVC Website..  So far, so good.. no errors.  But when I try to debug the newly created project (selecting the local website in my project - not the WebRoll in the CloudService dropdown, then hitting F5, or using the Debug menu), the browser pops up with the following message:

---

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     CustomErrorModule
Notification       SendResponse
Handler    ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0
Error Code     0x80070002
Config Error       Cannot read configuration file
Config File    applicationHost.config
Requested URL      http//localhost:49531/
Physical Path
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined
Config Source:

-1: 
    0:

---

This only happens when I have a Cloud Service / WebRoll association in my project.  I have no problem running the local debug when I create a website without introducing a CloudService - it runs localhost MVC applications with no problem at all.

The error indicates some sort of configuration file that I can't seem to find (applicationHost.config).

What am I doing wrong?  What's going on here that I'm missing?
I re-installed the Azure SDK a couple times.. that didn't seem to fix the issue either.

Comment: It looks like others that have run into the 500.19 error did so because a missing rewrite module. I have no idea if that's your issue but I would give that a try. You can get it from Web Installer, search for url-rewrite, or from here, http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite.

Comment: Check the answer from this post [Applicationhost.config is missing][1] and see if those help.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25338179/applicationhost-config-is-missing

Comment: Hey the error code indicates file not found. Check this http://hammadrajjoub.net/2013/08/20/hresult-0x80070002-visual-studio-2013-preview/

Comment: Does it run when you Host in azure. Also check if msrhtmi.DLL is in version which you are targeting